# В eclipse не устанавливается android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Пробую в Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
поставить android NDK. Скачиваю, распаковываю на C:\android-sdks. В эклипсе захожу Window->Preferences->Android->NDK и указываю там путь к папке с NDK. Но эклипс выдает ошибку "Not a valid NDK directory". Кто сталкивался подскажите что делать?

Comment: а почему бы вам не перейти на андроид студио, сейчас это довольно мощный инструмент и с установкой компонент  проблем не возникает..

Comment: Сликом старая версия adt плагина может?

Скачайте adt здесь https://github.com/khaledev/ADT

Comment: @Анна, а если сразу поставить сборку Eclipse для Android? Предварительно можно экспортировать настройки JEE и затащить их обратно после установки.

Comment: Ну или здесь глянуть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043047/adt-23-doesnt-like-ndk11
"Попробовать создать пустой файл ndk-build в папке NDK"